# When to use the subjunctive tense correctly?

Tags: subjonctif

In French coursework I have been required to complete, using the subjunctive tense is a required part of the mark scheme. I understand that it is activated by the term 'que' but I have been told multiple times that it is only certain phrases. What are these phrases and do they follow a pattern? Advice on using the tense on ditch would also be appreciated.

Comment: Une liste d'exemples : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif

Comment: Les règles pour le subjonctif en français sont d'une complexité qu'on trouve dix à vingt pages dans une grammaire. La langue écrite a adopté presque tout le système du subjonctif Latin. Au fond, c'est un poids mort pour la langue. Mais les écrivains n'ont pas le courage de jeter ce poids mort. Souvent le subjonctif est purement mécanique, sans logique. On peut constater qu'on veut se ďébarrasser du subjonctif dans quelques cas, mais au moment ces cas ne sont pas beaucoup.